# nested Array from LINQ c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datetime, virtual

I have the following  collection class

```
public class Customer
{
        public int Id{get;set}
        public DateTime StartTime { get; protected set; }
        public IList<ShoppingList> shoppingList{ get; protected set; }

}

public class shoppingList
{
    public int price{get;set;}
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have listcustomers

How do I convert it to a nested array so that I get shopping lists of each customer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var customers = listcustomers.Select(c=>c.shoppingList.ToArray())
                             .ToArray();
//get shoppingList array of customer 0
customers[0];
//get the first shoppingList of customer 0
customers[0][0];
```

Note that doing so won't track the info of customer, you just know the customer index and the corresponding `shoppingList` of that customer.

Comment: Yes that is true. But I dont want to keep the Customer type. I have a function which returns double[][]. for instance return new []{}..

Comment: Yes what you did return of course Customer[][], which is correct. but I what I need it to return is to return double[][], no casting :)

Comment: @JOY `double[][]` in fact can only stores **doubles**, so what actual values do you want? Your question is very confusing

Comment: Okie now this some king of result I expect, Added price for shoppinglist                                                         var points = [ [[2,5], [30,60], [50, 20]],
             [[2,5], [30,60], [50, 20]]];

Comment: @KingKing i think @JOY meant `c.shoppingList.Select(s=>s.Price).ToArray()`

Comment: @Grundy I did not think it's so hard for him to express what he actually wanted, also the confusing thing is he wants `double[][]` while the price should be `double` but he uses `int`, ... I would ask him more about what he actually wants, thanks.

Comment: @JOY what is the pair `[2,5]`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want?

```
 var points= listcustomers.Select(x => x.shoppingList
                                        .Select(shop => new[] { 
                                                         shop.Id, 
                                                         shop.price })).ToArray();
```